# how to calculate quadratic features in computer vision Neural Network

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, tensorflow, convolution

I am recently watching some tutorials for deep learning from Dr Andrew Ng on Youtube. Link is here[The Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ZhtwInuOD0)

There is a concept of *number of features* in **convolutional neural network** in **TensorFlow**'s [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros#convolution_and_pooling).

I don't quite understand why the *feature* is 32 or 64 here in conv layer1 or layer2?

Then I came to the [video](https://youtu.be/1ZhtwInuOD0?t=9m8s), there is also the concept of *Quadratic features*. It is calculated as *3 million* however. But how is it calculated?

Are the two *features* related in concept?

Comment: it's common to use powers of two for sizing filters or dense layers in neural networks

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for being so late in the response. I have just read your message.

The instructor is using $\frac{x^2}2$. So $\frac{2500\times 2500}2$, and this will get approx $3$ millions features.

BR

Answer (score 0):

What this means is:

1. 50x50 pixels image means 2500 unit pixels in your image. Then each unit is a feature, i.e.,

$x_1=\text{pixel}_1$, $x_2 = \text{pixel}_2$, $\cdots$, $x_{2500} = \text{pixel}_{2500}$.
A quadratic function means that you take all possible combinations of $x_ix_j$, for example $x_1^2$, $\ x_1x_2$, $\ x_1x_3$, $\ \cdots$, $\ x_1x_{2500}$, etc... this will give you a better outcome than considering just a linear function..., just get all the possible combinations and count them and you will get around $\frac{n^2}{2} = \frac{2500\ \times\ 2500}{2} \approx 3M$